# How to sort the last name of the bibliography alphabetically in elsevier

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

As we all know that elsevier supports three bibliographic style files (*.bst), i.e. elsarticle-num.bst, elsarticlenum-names.bst and elsarticle-harv.bst — the first one for the numbered scheme, the second for the numbered with new options of natbib.sty and the last one for the author year scheme.

My concern is how to sort the last names of the bibliography alphabetically? Moreover, all the author name should appear in numbered format.

Comment: The author-year style should sort authors alphabetically. So, I understand you want the numeric style, but with authors sorted by alphabet, rather than number? This would either result in the bibliography being practically unsorted, i.e. reference 2 before 1, for example, which is hardly useful for the reader when there are many citations. Or you would force the numbers to be consecutive as well, and then use them for `\cite`, resulting in the possibility that citation 2 occurs before 1 in the text (better, but still not very useful). What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want all the bibliography entries should be sorted according to the last name. I have used the style model5-names.bst, it helps upto certain extent.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. Alphabetical sorting with numeric citing style does not make sense. Or do I understand you wrongly? Why do you not create a minimal working example, that exemplifies your point and shows, what you have so far and what you want!?

Comment: For instance, `model5-names.bst` is APA style. It is an author-year style, there it makes sense to have authors in the bibliography sorted alphabetically. For a numeric style, it does not.

Comment: But I am not using the `authoryear` options in the document class. Therefore, the .bst `model5-names` works fine. Yes, my mistake i will place the MWE soon.

Comment: But if you do that, it happens exactly what I said (as you can see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elsevier-article-template-with-different-bibliography-styles/npwqmwvhvvrk#.WK6_j_JvDeQ)). Namely, that by forcing the references in the bibliography to be sorted by alphabet, the in-text citations do not occur in order anymore (i.e. reference 2 occurs before reference 1 in the text). It does not make sense to me. Is that really what you want, are you aware of this problem?